# How can I add Variable DnAttribute to dn?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

The @DnAttribute annotation could add an attribute to dn and using index  controlling attribute position in dn. If I want to add a variable length attribute to dn,how can I do that?
For example ,I want to add attribute  "ou" to dn,but i dont know how many ou i will insert.I add  @DnAttribute(value = "ou",index = 0)  annotation  on my pojo class.

```
@Id
@JsonIgnore
private Name dn; 
@DnAttribute(value = "uid",index = 1)
@Transient
private String uid;   
@DnAttribute(value = "ou",index = 0)
@Transient
private String ou;
```

And then I add this attribute to my pojo.

```
{"uid":"admin4" ,"ou":"java,ou=it"}
```

I want to add an entry and I hope its dn="uid=admin4,ou=java,ou=it,baseDn",but I get this Exception:

```
 "org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException, [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'uid=admin4,ou=java\\,ou\\=it'"
```

It looks like springldap escape special symbols when getCalculatedId.
What's more,I dont want to make the parameter omit the first "ou".Of course I can income a integral ou and concatenate strings.But is there some method to add a variable length attribute to dn like making ou as a list?

Comment: As you may have noticed from the error message, the notation: "ou":"java,ou=it" is actually setting one 'ou' attribute with the value 'java,ou=it' (and comma is escaped). It seems to me that you may want to separate "ou":"java", "ou":"it". But that's as far as I know about SpringBoot ldap support.

Comment: yeah when you make your entry's dn equals null ldaptemplate will use getCalculatedId method to splice dn .In that method it uses a for() to add every DnAttribute to dn so that it can build a entry. I can't separate "ou" cause i don't know how many "ou" i will set so i have to  pass a String .

Comment: And now I know this error because dn is a LdapNaming ,it can't splice String.But this still does not solve my question.